# IOS 10 objectForKey("key") compatibility

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I'm working on my app compatibility with IOS10 and I have a problem when execution this code :

```
if let results = NSJSONSerialization.TryJSONObjectWithData(data, options: []) as? NSDictionary {
    print(" results : \(results)");

    if let networkPosts = results["results"] as? NSMutableArray {
        print(" here");

                for i in 0 ..< networkPosts.count {
                    let post:Post = Post(postDictionary: networkPosts[i] as! NSDictionary, context: (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! 

AppDelegate).coreDataHelper.managedObjectContext);
}
        }
    }
```

I can see the results so the JSON is ok but after I can't see the result key of the dictionary.
"Here" is never printed on my console . I've try making a breakpoint and same it doesn't pass through there.
I've also try with `.objectForKey("key")` but same result :/

Can someone help me please ?

If I use `results["results"] as? [[String: Any]]`

Then

> networkPosts[i] as! NSDictionary always fails

Comment: post JSON that you receive

Comment: Please show us your json response.

Comment: Do you have `results` key in your json? or is it `result`?

Comment: I have "results" in my key. All works well before I started testing on iOS10

Comment: You should not use `NSMutableArray/Dictionary` in Swift at all. Use `var` and Swift `Array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the NSJSONReadingMutableContainers option when using TryJSONObjectWithData to make arrays and dictionaries mutable

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSJSONReadingOptions

Example tested with Playground for Swift 3:

```
let jsonString = "{\"name\":\"Mattia\",\"iosDevices\":[\"iPhone6\",\"iPad Air 2\",\"iPhone6+\"]} 
let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

if let results = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [.mutableContainers]) as? NSDictionary {
    print(" results : \(results)");

    if let networkPosts = results["iosDevices"] as? NSMutableArray {
        print(" here");
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use MutableContainers instead of NSMutableArray ?

Comment: I Have the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'JSONSerialization'". Am I missing an import ? I have only Foundation and UIKIt

Comment: Melanie that is the version for Swift 3. For Swift 2 you can just use NSJSONSerialization instead

Comment: You don't need MutableContainers in Swift. Assigning the value to a `var`iable makes it mutable.

Comment: Type NSJSONSerialization has no member 'jsonObject'

Comment: For Swift 2: try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)